# How to draw only what is visible on-screen with gtk-cairo

Tags: c, performance, gtk, scaling, cairo

I have a `analyze(canvas)` function that performs a variety of operations on a `GdkPixbuf` which looks like this:

```
rotate(); // in respect to center
scale();
draw();
convert_to_pixbuf();
get_bounding_box(&w, &h);
set_canvas_size(w, h);
store_surface(surface);
queue_draw(); // changes canvas size allocation to wh and invokes draw() signal on canvas
```

Calling `cairo_paint(crDest)` after a large scaling is VERY slow, which is the problem per se.

and the `draw()` callback looks like this:

```
render_from_stored_surface();
gdk_window_input_shape_combine_region(); // makes potentially rotated/scaled image gdkwindow to be shaped, not square (i.e erases transparent pixels)
```

If I perform the scaling in the `draw()` it is fast, I assume because it will only update the portion that is visible or "dirty". Aside from writing more code to align it properly, the resulting image however looks ugly, jagged or so to say.

---

If indeed, this is the reason why it is so slow, how do I tell cairo to work on the area that is visible (similarly to what happens behind the scenes around `draw()`) inside the `analyze()` function, then check whether update is needed in `draw()` and pass extends to `analyze()` so that it clips it accordingly?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused and do not understand the question. I do not even know what to ask you for making it clearer. The best idea that I have is to leave this comment and perhaps you can make things clearer.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I'm sorry. I'm really trying, but it's not easy when I am confused myself. But to keep it simple and short, to decrease the chances of confusion I'd just say this: Scaling is too slow when performed on `cairo_t` that I created, but not on the `cairo_t` that is given by GTK on the `draw` signal, but there the rotated image would look jagged.

Comment: I'd need a way to optimize this scaling while maintaining the good appearance of the rotated pixbuf (`cairo_rotate`). I need a large scaling up to x32, because it is actually an implementation for zoom.

Comment: And no I cannot perform the rotation on draw's `cr`, because I needed to convert a surface to pixbuf, analyze it and modify the drawing area's size, which cannot happen in draw or on the same `cr`